# Randomly answer the question with previously marked option intact in a Javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, store

I made a '**Quiz Application**' in which I want to add some **extra functionality** like

> 1. When I clicked on the random **'Question Number'** printed on the **'Question List Section'** then redirect to that **question** & if the question is **'Already Answered'** then keep the **marked option intact**.
> 2. When I clicked the '**Previous' & 'Next'** button I can go **back & forward**, with **'Previously Marked Option'** intact.

I am able to make the **'Randomly go to the Question'** functionality with **'go to the Next & Previous Question'** functionality but I ***cannot understand*** how to make the ***'previously marked Option'*** intact whatever the user marked along with the **correct answer**.

*Some Html Part*

```
        <div class="question-box">
            <div class="question-text">
                <!-- Q1. The term “biology” was introduced by?  -->
            </div>
            <div class="question-option">
                <!-- <div class="option">A.&ensp;Aristotle</div>
                <div class="option">B.&ensp;Darwin</div>
                <div class="option">C.&ensp;Lamarck & Treviranus</div>
                <div class="option">D.&ensp;Linnaeus</div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="question-direction">
                <button type="button" class="btn prev">Prev</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn next">Next</button> 
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="answer-box">
            <div class="answer-container">
                <!-- <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
                <div>5</div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="answer-direction">
                <button type="button" class="btn submit">Submit</button> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

*Some JavaScript Part*

```
        // prev question
        let q_pre = document.querySelector('.prev');
        q_pre.addEventListener('click', function(){

            if(Q_count === 0) {
                q_pre.disable = 'true';
            } else {
                Q_count--;
                setQuestion(); 
            }
           
        });
        

        // next question
        let q_nxt = document.querySelector('.next');
        q_nxt.addEventListener('click', function(){ 

            if(Q_count === Q_len - 1){
                q_nxt.disable = 'true';
            } else {
                Q_count++;
                setQuestion(); 
            }
                 
        });
```

Here is the   [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Bdeb121/hgo73d1u/3/)   for my quiz app.

Comment: We need to see some HTML. The JS is kinda useless without HTML

Comment: @Rojo It's visible in the fiddle link provided. But agreed, it would be nice to have it immediately visible.

Comment: Before posting links to code or inserting code, [learn how to make a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)